# Why I should not compress images in HTTP headers?

Tags: apache, http-headers, compression, mod-deflate

I read some articles about HTTP headers compression. Today I installed YSlow and it recommends that I compress the resources (text/html, javascript, css and images). Now I'm reading the documentation for [Apache mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) but in the example don't compress images.

Should I or should I not compress images in my site?

Comment: YSlow recommends that *images* be compressed? Are you sure? That sounds like odd advice.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your images should already be compressed - any extra compression won't have any noticeable effect on filesize, but will increase processing time.

- .png files [use DEFLATE compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression) already.
- .jpg files [generally use lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg#JPEG_compression).
- .gif files [use LZW compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format).

Compressing files that have already been compressed very rarely results in a reduction in filesize, and can often increase filesize.

Comment: @Agusti: if your images happen to be uncompressed, like say, .bmp files, you should convert them to .png or .jpg, as appropriate, and then serve the converted version, of course :)

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes thank you but my images are .png files, btw it's very good to know this tip :-D

Comment: @Martinho Good point - that was what I meant by "Your images should already be compressed", but it's good to make it explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Images such as GIF, JPEG or PNG are already compressed via highly specialized algorithms that achieve better result than general purpose algorithms such as deflate.

Therefore, re-compressing them yields little to no gain in size, and can even make files bigger, with the added cost of server-side processing.

So, in other words... do not compress images.

Answer (score 0):

SVGs should be compressed by [Apache mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) as

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
```

More information at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html.